# Update to @cds/angular@5.0.2

Tags: angular, vmware-clarity

Any idea what the problem is when updating @cds/angular from 5.0.1 to 5.0.2

All my angular packages are 11.1.0

-Jani

```
npm ERR! Found: @angular/common@11.2.2
npm ERR! node_modules/@angular/common
npm ERR!   @angular/common@"^11.1.0" from the root project
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
npm ERR! peer @angular/common@"^9.0.0" from @cds/angular@5.0.2
npm ERR! node_modules/@cds/angular
npm ERR!   @cds/angular@"^5.0.1" from the root project
```

Answer (score 0):

update your local angular version.
your angular cli is updated to 11.0 but angular is still on 9.0.

Run command ng --version .

verify the local and global version of @cds/angular@

Comment: both the cli and angular is 11.0. I don't have 9.0 anywhere.

Comment: check ng --version from your UI code and also from outside the code repo ..and check the status of output

Comment: Outside project
Angular CLI: 11.0.3
Node: 14.15.0
OS: linux x64

Angular:
...
Ivy Workspace:
`
Inside project
Angular CLI: 11.0.3
Node: 14.15.0
OS: linux x64

Angular: undefined
...
Ivy Workspace: <error>

I wonder what that undefined and error means ?

Comment: Sorry I was in the wrong folder, this is inside client project:
Angular CLI: 11.1.1
Node: 14.15.0
OS: linux x64

Angular: 11.1.0
... animations, cdk, common, compiler, compiler-cli, core, forms
... language-service, platform-browser, platform-browser-dynamic
... router
Ivy Workspace: Yes

Comment: I think your global version of cds-angular is different from local project's cds-angular

Comment: if nothing of above gives a clue about the solution then I think you have updated your mac to SUR .. there is something wrong with EPEM process..I don't have much idea about it

Comment: there is no global cds-angular and I use the linux subsystem (wls2) in windows. I went ahead and forced the update. It seems to work so far. Thanks.